# How to crop image b/w these five points in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to crop image inside theses five points
I have done some code, but it did not work.

I want to crop image inside these five points:

[image: binary image with 5 points]

```
bw=baseimage;
cc=regionprops(bw,'Centroid');
fixedPoints=cat(1,cc.Centroid);

bx1=floor(fixedPoints(1));
bx5=floor(fixedPoints(5));
by1=floor(fixedPoints(6));
by5=floor(fixedPoints(10));
base_crop=imcrop(n_im_base,[bx1 by1 bx5 by5]);
figure,imshow(base_crop);
```

Comment: Hi @Khataab! Please share the code you wrote, and describe how exactly it does not work (what is the actual behavior, how it differs from the expected one?).

Answer (score 1):

Imcrop take the following argument `imcrop(bw,[xmin ymin width height])`.

So you need to determine `xmin`,`ymin`,`width` and `height`

```
%We load the bw picture
bw = im2bw(imread('im.jpg'));
%Determine the centroid
s = regionprops(bw,'centroid');
%struct to matrice
c = reshape([s.Centroid],2,length(s)).'
%crop the image: min(c) will determine xmin and ymin, and max(c)-min(c) will determine the width and height
I = imcrop(bw,[min(c) max(c)-min(c)]);
imshow(I);
```

[image]

If your 5 points do not form a rectangle you can also create a mask in order to show only the region of interest:

```
%returns the 2-D convex hull of the points (X,Y)
k = convhull(c(:,1),c(:,2));
%create the mask
mask = poly2mask(c(k,1),c(k,2),size(bw,1),size(bw,2));
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, It got me close to the solution, but I don't want to include these five points,it must be invisible.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include to add on top of your image the desired area of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, which doesn't need the *Image Processing Toolbox*, and might be more straight-forward.

```matlab
% Read input image
img = imread('swq1I.jpg');

% Get rid of JPG artifacts ("im2bw", "imbinarize")
img(img < 100) = 0;
img(img > 100) = 255;

figure(1);
imshow(img);

% Row and column wise summation for detection of xmin, etc. 
x = sum(img, 1);
y = sum(img, 2);

% First and last non-zero elements per row and column describe the bounding rect
xmin = find(x, 1, 'first');
xmax = find(x, 1, 'last');
ymin = find(y, 1, 'first');
ymax = find(y, 1, 'last');

% Crop by simple array indexing
crop = img(ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax);

figure(2);
imshow(crop);
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Output]